# sending outerhtml with json makes trouble

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to send some parts of the html source code with an ajax call.

If I define the data to be sent for the ajax call in this way:

```
var content={};


content['mypart1']='my content 1';
content['mypart2']='my content 2';
content=JSON.stringify(content);
```

In the console I see this string for sending:

```
... , content: "{\"mypart1\":\"my content 1\",\"mypart2\":\"my content 2\"}" ...
```

It works. After `$test=json_decode($post['content']);` I have the wanted array of my content parts.

Now I need to use it with real content parts, so i tried this;

```
$("[myselector]").each(function(i, part) {
content['mypart1']=$(part)[0].outerHTML;
content['mypart2']=$(part)[0].outerHTML;
});
content=JSON.stringify(content);
```

Now I see in the console, that the wanted html code is correctly inside the string.

But if I send this, I see in the console that inside the string there are multiple ///-signs and the keys are also inside \" now. 
`"{\"mypart1\":\"<div id=\\\"myid\\\" data-mydataid=\\\"123456\\\" class=\\\".....`

I think it was because this faulty string that the jason_decode won't work correctly.

`$test=json_decode($post['content']);`

With this data I won't receive the wanted array, $test is empty.

What caused the multiple ///-signs and /-around the keys and how I can prevent this?

Thanks a lot for helping and explaining.

Maybe i have to unserialize the outerhtml part before add them to a stringify string?

This is the Ajax call

```
do_ajax_call({   
'content': content,
...
 });

function do_ajax_call(data,ajaxurl){ 
....
$.ajax({    url: ajaxurl,
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType:'json',            
            success: function(result){
    ...
});
```

Comment: Did you see this error on closing quotes? it happens all the time  `content['mypart1]`

Comment: ops, thats a error of my post, in the code its correctly, i updat the post. thanks for this notice

Comment: Show us your AJAX request where you actually send this data as well.

Comment: post your ajax code along with php

Comment: i've add the part of the ajax-call

Comment: because to differentiate your string from the attributes which has double quote, try your html attributes with single quote instead double, because entire string already in double quote

Comment: @manny this wont change anything, the unwanted / signs are also inside the string by do the ajax-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-primary" id="bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%"></div>
<b id="import"></b>
```

js:

```
var data = {};//js object
data["key1"] = document.getElementById('import').outerHTML;
data["key2"] = document.getElementById('bar').outerHTML;

        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            complete: function () {
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
```

php :

```
echo'<pre>';print_r($_POST);die;
```

output :

```
<pre>Array
(
    [key1] => <b id="import"></b>
    [key2] => <div class="progress-bar progress-primary" id="bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%"></div>
)
```

This is tested code

Comment: Hi, if i see it wright, the main-difference between your and my code is, that you dont stringify the "data" before you send it. If i trie the same, the ajax call looks a little bit better. the multiple / are away. But i see in the console a text "object" before the string "content: Object { "mypart1":..." and on my php file i get the error " json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given", if i print_r the $post - this is the result [content] => Array (   [0] => )

Comment: I already mentioned in my answer that m not using array its an object in js portion so not need to do decode just use it like $_POST array i.e array of object

Comment: yes, in javascript i define the content as object too, so i cannot see the difference?

Comment: do echo var_dump($_POST);die;

Comment: ok, var_dump returns array(1) {
    [0]=>    string(719) "....} there is all content inside the [0], but i need it seperate for each key!? Something goes wrong, and i cant see what

Comment: you need to create an array of object dynamic so existing object will never overlap, now your object is overlapping or concatenating, I dong know try to iterate it with dynamic array of object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190756/discussion-between-m-hemant-and-greg).

Comment: i found the problem :-() a name of a key contained a dot array['my.name'], it seems that this caused the main trouble of all... thanks a lot !